# magento 2.2 load model vs objectManager: the first returns the wrong id while the second returns the correct one

Tags: magento2, shipment

I'm a bit puzzled about how the load() and objectManager are different. I have a model where I inject the order model to load an order by it's ID, then I use the order to get its shipments:

```
public function __construct(Magento\Sales\Model\Order $order) {
  $this->_order = $order;
}

public function getShipment($oid) {
  $order = $this->_order->load($oid);
  // I always have only one shipment per order so I can call directly the firstItem method
  $shipment = $order->getShipmentsCollection()->getFirstItem();
}
```

The problem with this code is this:

```
$this->_order->load($oid);
```

calls the order correctly (if I pass the id 32, then it loads the order with id 32, if I pass the id 33, then it loads the order with id 33 and so on), but

```
$shipment = $order->getShipmentsCollection()->getFirstItem();
```

calls always the same shipment, so no matter if the order loaded is 31, 32, 33 etc etc the shipment returned is always the same (eg: shipment with id 20).

If I substitute

```
$this->_order->load($oid);
```

with the objectManager

```
$order = $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($oid);
```

then the shipment returned is correct, so for order 31 I get shipment 20, for order 32 I get the shipment 21 and so on.

Why does the load() method always return the same shipment on different orders?

Answer (score 1):

The difference between $this->_order->load($oid) and $objectManager->create('\Magento\Sales\Model\Order')->load($oid) is that the former uses the same Order object and the latter creates a new one each time.

I suspect the reason why getShipmentsCollection() returns the shipments collection of the first order every time, is simply that the order model caches the collection. If you create a new model, no cache is present.

Loading an entity via a model is a Magento 1 style. The Magento 2 way is to use a repository from the Api:

```
use Magento\Sales\Api\OrderRepositoryInterface;

/**
 * @var OrderRepositoryInterface
 */
protected $orderRepository;

public function __construct(
    OrderRepositoryInterface $orderRepository
)
{
    $this->orderRepository = $orderRepository;
}

public function getShipment($oid) {
    $order = $this->orderRepository->get($oid);

    // I always have only one shipment per order so I can call directly the firstItem method
    $shipment = $order->getShipmentsCollection()->getFirstItem();
    return $shipment;
}
```

Comment: "Loading an entity via a model is a Magento 1 style. The Magento 2 way is to use a repository from the Api"

you are right. The problem I find with the repository is that they throw errors instead of letting you try/catch them. So if I use $this->orderRepository->get($oid) then the code throws errors if it doesn't find the $oid I'm looking for and the execution stops. With model I'm able to manage code and errors better. Anyway, I understand about cache, thank you very much for your explanation, it was very clear